# Javascript async events and using a global variable locally (like a counter)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope

I'm not sure my question is understandable. I don't know of a better way to explain it without an example.

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
function foo(obj){
    var index = 0;
    obj.onstart = function(){
        ++index;
        console.log('start', index);
    }
    obj.onfinish = function(){
        console.log('finish', index);
    }
}
```

Now let's assume I have the following test case:

```
foo(slow_connection);
foo(fast_connection);
```

Basically, the `onfinish` of `slow_connection` is triggered after the `onstart` of `fast_connection` causing the following output.

```
start 1
start 2
finish 2      <-- This should be 1!
finish 2
```

**PS:** I can't change the arguments of `foo()` the only code I can change is inside `foo()`.

Comment: ummm, Can't really answer good one, without your real code, but why won't you use a separate index variable for each connection or use `setTimeout`?

Comment: The index variable is my problem. How do I "count" up while using this number locally inside `onstart` and `onfinish`? The `setTimeout` idea is completely unusable in my case.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to answer with my real code since it spans several hundred lines of code.

Comment: If you can't sync between the two, and must use one variable, **I'm afraid it can't be done.**

Comment: @Joseph I'm not sure I understand your question. start/finish are just events I threw in as an example. They could be a mouseover/out or ajax start/finish. The point is that I need to have a local variable as their index and a global one as the counter.

Comment: @gdoron No, I can use any amount of variables, anywhere. I just can't change the arguments of `foo()`.

Comment: But you can't give a parameter to the `foo` function to indicate who trigger it, so it doesn't help you...

Comment: Can you put `index` outside of `foo()`, then inside `foo()` do `index++; obj.index = index;` and then use `obj.index` inside handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
function foo(obj){
  var index = 0;

  obj.onstart = function(){
    ++index;
    console.log('start', index);
  };

  // bind onfinish using a "copy" of the current index.
  obj.onfinish = (function (idx) {
    return function () {
      console.log('finish', idx);
    };
  }(index));
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! I knew it had to be about closures. Thanks!